# Gulp / Node.js error: connect ECONNREFUSED

Tags: javascript, node.js, cmd, gulp

I am currently running a local server using WAMP and I am trying to set up Gulp.js. Here are the contents of my gulpfile:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    sass = require('gulp-ruby-sass'),
    autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
    minifycss = require('gulp-minify-css'),
    minifyhtml = require('gulp-minify-html'),
    jshint = require('gulp-jshint'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename'),
    clean = require('gulp-clean'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    notify = require('gulp-notify'),
    cache = require('gulp-cache'),
    livereload = require('gulp-livereload'),
    lr = require('tiny-lr'),
    server = lr();

gulp.task('styles', function() {
    gulp.src('src/styles/main.scss')
        .pipe(sass({ style: 'expanded' }))
        .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 version', 'safari 5', 'ie 8', 'ie 9', 'opera 12.1', 'ios 6', 'android 4'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/assets/css'))
        .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
        .pipe(minifycss())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'))
        .pipe(livereload(server))
        .pipe(notify({ message: 'Styles task complete' }));
});

gulp.task('html', function() {
    gulp.src('src/*.php')
        .pipe(minifyhtml())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
        .pipe(livereload(server))
        .pipe(notify({ message: 'HTML task complete' }));
});

gulp.task('default', function() {
    gulp.run('html');
});
```

And here is the output I am getting  when I run `gulp`:

```
[gulp] Using gulpfile C:\wamp\www\SawyerK\gulpfile.js
[gulp] Starting 'default'...
gulp.run() has been deprecated. Use task dependencies or gulp.watch task trigger
ing instead.
[gulp] Starting 'html'...
[gulp] Finished 'html' after 132 ms
[gulp] Finished 'default' after 134 ms
[gulp] gulp-notify: [Gulp notification] HTML task complete

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
    at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
    at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:895:19)
```

From what I have found, this error is thrown because something else is using the port Node wants or something like that? However, I am not completely sure if that's right and I definitely don't have a clue how to fix it. Any thoughts? Thanks!

Edit: I seem to have it narrowed down to gulp-notify if that helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that you use livereload twice, in styles task and html. Maybe it's better use livereload with watcher:

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {
  var server = livereload();
  gulp.watch('build/**').on('change', function(file) {
      server.changed(file.path);
  });
});
```

update:
Sorry, was wrong =) Here is a great article, and second part that shows how to use watch task.
[link](http://markgoodyear.com/2014/01/getting-started-with-gulp/) To work with livereload you need to start the server with listen method.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But now I have another problem. For example, I want to use your watch function but also make it run the appropriate function to handle the files and then reload the page when that is done. This is what I currently have but it doesn't work:

    gulp.task('watch', function() {
     var server = livereload();
     gulp.watch('src/**').on('change', function(file) {
      server.changed(file.path);
     });
     gulp.watch('src/*.php', ['minifyhtml']);
    });  Edit: How on earth do you make this comment accept formatting? I can't hit enter for a new line or format the code.

Comment: to pass code in comments just add ` symbol) like `var foo = "bar";`

Comment: This is what that does, it doesn't keep the formatting at all.

`gulp.task('watch', function() {

 var server = livereload();

 gulp.watch('src/**').on('change', function(file) {
  server.changed(file.path);
 });

 gulp.watch('src/*.php', ['minifyhtml']);
});`

Answer (score 0):

Are you by chance on Windows? My dev team ran into this issue it looks on Windows 7+ gulp-notify requires Growl. :/

You can download the exe at gulpforwindows.com, and I believe you will need to restart your machine as well.

https://github.com/mikaelbr/gulp-notify/issues/30

https://github.com/mikaelbr/gulp-notify#requirements

Comment: Note: gulp-notify now can fallback to "taskbar balloons" if Growl isn't installed now. :-)